# Preprocess list of strings efficently

Tags: python, string

I have a list of strings. Example string,

```
mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists/*therapeutic use, Adult, Aged, Aged/*effects, Antihypertensive Agents/*therapeutic use, Blood Glucose/*drug effects, Celiprolol/*therapeutic use, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension/*drug therapy, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
```

For each term in the string (where) terms are separated by commas, I would like to delete all text after the '/'. If there is no backslash, do nothing.

For example, I wish the resulting string to be like so,

```
 mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists, Adult, Aged, Aged, Antihypertensive Agents, Blood Glucose, Celiprolol, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
```

I would then like to delete any duplicate values in the string (eg. Aged). Desired string,

```
mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists, Adult, Aged, Antihypertensive Agents, Blood Glucose, Celiprolol, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
```

I have written this code which works for one string, but am looking for a more efficient way to do this for a list of strings:

```
import string
mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists/*therapeutic use, Adult, Aged, Aged/*effects, Antihypertensive Agents/*therapeutic use, Blood Glucose/*drug effects, Celiprolol/*therapeutic use, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension/*drug therapy, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
newMesh = []
for each in mesh.split(","):
    newMesh.append(each.split('/', 1)[0].lstrip(' '))
newMesh = list(set(newMesh))
meshString = ",".join(newMesh)
print(meshString)
```

Note: the order of the terms in the string is irrelevant.

Comment: Please stop adding erroneous tags, what you have is _not_ a dataframe.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Apologies - not sure what I was thinking...

Comment: Wrap into function and apply it to map. `list_of_strings = list(map(your_function, list_of_strings))`

Comment: This code looks about as good as it can get. Don't be afraid of the loop/append model for building collections with complex logic. A couple of minor changes: you could make `newMesh` a `set` at the start (use `newMesh.add()` when needed) and you could skip the conversion to a `list` before `','.join`. Those would avoid creation of some intermediate results. But they probably won't save a whole lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists/*therapeutic use, Adult, Aged, Aged/*effects, Antihypertensive Agents/*therapeutic use, Blood Glucose/*drug effects, Celiprolol/*therapeutic use, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension/*drug therapy, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
import re
s = re.sub("\/\*[\w\s]+", '', mesh)
final_string = []
for i in re.split(",", s):
    if i not in final_string:
        final_string.append(i)

new_final_string = ', '.join(final_string)
print(new_final_string)
```

Output:

```
'Adrenergic beta-Antagonists,  Adult,  Aged,  Antihypertensive Agents,  Blood Glucose,  Celiprolol,  Female,  Glucose Tolerance Test,  Humans,  Hypertension,  Male,  Middle Aged,  Prospective Studies'
```

Comment: Whats the most efficient way to remove the duplicate tokens from this string?

Comment: Have edited to correct error - (eg. Adrenergic beta-Antagonists is a single token)

Answer (score 0):

With `re.sub()` function and `set` object(for faster item search):

```
import re

mesh = "Adrenergic beta-Antagonists/*therapeutic use, Adult, Aged, Aged/*effects, Antihypertensive Agents/*therapeutic use, Blood Glucose/*drug effects, Celiprolol/*therapeutic use, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension/*drug therapy, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies"
word_set = set()
result = []

for w in re.sub(r'/[^,]+', '', mesh).split(','):
    w = w.strip()
    if w not in word_set:
        result.append(w)
        word_set.add(w)
result = ', '.join(result)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
Adrenergic beta-Antagonists, Adult, Aged, Antihypertensive Agents, Blood Glucose, Celiprolol, Female, Glucose Tolerance Test, Humans, Hypertension, Male, Middle Aged, Prospective Studies
```